# Finding inverse of implicitly defined symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have an$\ n$ by$\ n$ matrix$\ A$ where
$$\ A_{i,j}=\frac{\varepsilon^{i+j+1}}{{i+j+1}} $$
for a general$\ \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$. The matrix is symmetric but finding eigenvectors seems to be a difficult path to take (i.e. finding eigendecomposition or SVD) and I'm trying to find a general$\ A^{-1} $. Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't $A$ equal to $\epsilon E B E$ where $E = \text{diag}(\epsilon^i)$ and $B$ does not depend on $\epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\varepsilon DCD$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\varepsilon,\varepsilon^2,\ldots,\varepsilon^n)$ and $C$ is the [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix) given by $c_{ij}=1/(i+j+1)$. So, you may use the formula for the [inverse of Cauchy matrix](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Cauchy_Matrix) to obtain $A^{-1}$.